# React component re-render on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const x = [];

const App = props => <div style={styles}>{JSON.stringify(x)}</div>;

render(<App queries={x} />, document.getElementById('root'));

setInterval(x => x.push(Math.random()), 1000, x);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why doesn't the App component rerender when I mutate the object that I passed to it as a prop.

Whenever I close and reopen React Dev Tools, it shows the new props.
[image]

What is happening here? Please help me understand.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: There's actually no component with the proper lifecycle or state management present with the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in this case is not related to setState. Sure React will automatically re-render when state changes (as long as you didn't do something like use a PureComponent and then mutate the array or object). But you are doing a render from the root and this has nothing to do with react state as your state exists outside of react.

From the [react docs on render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will
>   perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
>   reflect the latest React element.

So would need to call render again at the root level for React to reconcile the changes. Also it's better practice to make a new object/array. So in this case you could do `x = x.concat(..)` and then render again.

```
let x = [];

const App = props => <div>{props.queries.toString()}</div>;

const renderApp = (queries) => ReactDOM.render(<App queries={queries} />, document.getElementById('root'));

setInterval(() => {
  x = x.concat(Math.random());
  renderApp(x);
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/p7zhs55q/1/

Of course the more usual thing is to use local react state inside react components but it's good to have an understanding of this, and this is how you could implement some global state into react if you weren't using something like redux.

Comment: This may work but that is not how react is intended to be used. You will have to manually trigger re-renders when you think that the underlying data has changed which is about the same as calling `forceUpdate()`. Instead OP should create a container component that takes care of the updating. You will lose all the advantages of batching updates and the like if you do manual renders.

Comment: I agree this is unusual and maybe they OP doesn't know about react state, I was just answering the question as it was put forward (passing external state into React). But calling setState will re-render the component too unless you implemented a check in shouldComponentUpdate. In the case above you could do something similar with `if (state !== nextState) renderApp(nextState)`

Comment: Then is it not the case that a component would automatically rerender whenever its props change? @DominicTobias

Comment: No a component will only re-render if: 1) the parent render function was called 2) this.setState was called in the component 3) this.forceUpdate was called (not recommended) - and if it's not a functional component as you've written but a class, then also only if `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true (it's by default true for React.Component and does a shallow equality check on props and state for React.PureComponent)

Comment: However if props do change that means that the parent has changed them and the component gets re-rendered (props come from the parent and are passed down to the component, the component itself does not change props, only state)

Comment: Glad to help, if you have any questions let me know. It can be confusing at first but will make sense after a while. As the other answer insinuates you will generally be changing state within your components (not calling render again). If `App` has state and passes that to children components, that will be `props` to the children and so on in a tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

Mutating the data that you pass as props does not trigger a re-render of the component. There is no observer that takes notice of your mutation on that object that could trigger it. In case you have data that changes during the lifetime of a component [you need to use state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const x = [];

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        queries: this.props.queries,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(
            () => this.setState(state => ({queries: [...state.queries, Math.random()]}))
        ), 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return <div style={styles}>{JSON.stringify(this.state.queries)}</div>;
    }
}

render(<App queries={x} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This code will initialize the component state with the queries passed via props. When the component did mount it will start the interval which will append a new random number to the state. Calling `setState()` will trigger a re-render with the new state. Never mutate props.